# Why does the Bookmark Property not work in my MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access

I have a continous form on which the `.AllowAdditions=False`. There is a button that will add a new record by using the following code:

```
Dim bkm As Variant
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Unit", , dbAppendOnly)

With rs
    .AddNew
    .Fields("UnitID") = DMax("UnitID", "tbl_Unit") + 1
    .Fields("ObjektID") = 0
    .Fields("UnitTypID") = 0
    .Update
    bkm = .Bookmark
End With

Me.Requery
Me.Recordset.Bookmark = bkm
End Sub
```

The record is added as expected, but the bookmark method of jumping to the newly added record in the form, does not work. I get the run time error **3159: Not a valid bookmark**. As far as I can tell, I am following the same logic that Microsoft provides in their documentation page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/mark-a-position-in-a-dao-recordset). The error occurs on line `Me.Recordset.Bookmark = bkm`
Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Bookmarks of `.OpenRecordset` and Forms never match, even if both operate on the same table. You will need `Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark`. See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925712/restoring-a-continuous-form-after-requery

Comment: That was the missing piece of information that I lacked. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bookmark belongs to a recordset, not a table. So try:

```vb
Dim UnitId As Long
Dim rs     As DAO.Recordset

UnitId = DMax("UnitID", "tbl_Unit") + 1

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Unit", , dbAppendOnly)
With rs
    .AddNew
    .Fields("UnitID") = UnitId
    .Fields("ObjektID") = 0
    .Fields("UnitTypID") = 0
    .Update
    .Close
End With

Me.Requery
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "UnitID = " & UnitId & ""
If Not rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
rs.Close
```

Comment: Changing `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Unit", , dbAppendOnly)` to `Set rs = me.RecordsetClone` might work too and result in simpler code with less overhead, assuming that recordset is editable.

Comment: @ErikA: _assuming that recordset is editable_ ... but isn't that exactly what `.AllowAdditions=False` prohibits?

Comment: Nope, `.AllowAdditions = False` just disables the add record button and default add record row in continuous forms (and perhaps the DoCmd stuff to add records no longer works, never tried that).

Comment: @ErikA: Never tried that, but I did a test and can confirm that option. Thanks!